# Emacs: how to make custom aware of new code?

Tags: emacs, elisp

Say that I write this:

```
(defgroup foobar nil "doc")
```

and evaluate it.
Currently I'm not able to do `customize-group` `foobar`.
Only after restarting Emacs it becomes available.
How can I do this without restarting?

### EDIT

Thanks for the answer, but it isn't yet complete. Here I define
a face for the newly created group.
It's not visible on calling `(customize-group 'foobar)`.

```
(defface foobar-face
  '((t (:inherit 'font-lock-type-face)))
  "Face for displaying types."
  :group 'foobar)
```

Actually, even for a group that already exists, I can't get new defcustoms
to appear before restarting.

Comment: If the customize group buffer already exists, I find that I need to kill it before calling `customize-group` again to make newly added items show up.

Comment: Excellent! Please do add this to the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The interactive spec for `customize-group` looks for symbols with a non-nil `custom-group` property.  The `custom-group` property contains the list of customizable variables in the group, so you need to add at least one `defcustom` that refers to your new group in order for your new group to be available through interactive `customize-group`.

(You can also circumvent the interactive spec and call `(customize-group 'foobar)` directly.)

Also, if the customize group buffer already exists, and you add new items to it, you need to kill the old buffer before `customize-group` will show the new items - otherwise it just switches to the buffer.

Comment: `defcustom` or `defface`, that is.